# C++ Does the compiler optimize out known statements?

Tags: c++

This question no doubt would constitute premature optimization, however I want to know *what the compiler will do with this* to learn more about how the compiler works.

In the below example, can I expect the compiler to produce 2 or 3 functions with the `if` statements removed, or is it always going to execute that `if` statement on every iteration of the loop? Is the compiler going to optimize out the `if` statement on the basis that the function is called only with a parameter that is known at compile time?

```
void myfunction(int a) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
      // here are various calculations that are the same regardless of a
      if (a == 0) {
         dosomething1(someValue);
      } else if (a == 1) {
         dosomething2(someValue);
      } else {
         dosomething3(someValue);
      }
   }
}

myfunction(0);
myfunction(1);
```

Comment: ¿Why don't you try to compile it and check whether compiler you are using will optimize or not?

Comment: @user7860670 how do I do that?

Comment: How can the compiler know a `const` expression for `a`? Think of having that function compiled into a static library.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if you fear it can not ( which is typically true ) you have a first argument to NOT write functions to c/cpp files but into headers with inline instead to get best optimization, even if it breaks "old style" coding guidelines.

Comment: @Klaus I never said that there's anything wrong with `inline` functions, that's just a consequence of that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I never said that you said... it was meant simply as a guidance. As compilers becomes better and better, writing code in c/c++ files becomes more and more obsolete ( only my observation ) or switching LTO every time on. I know, there are millions of people who avoid writing any line of code to header files... for what reason ever... and I can't believe for compile time issues,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends entirely on the compiler and optimization level.

For example, GCC 10 will transform loops to hoist invariants out at **-O3** level. We can see in this demo ([Godbolt link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rc46hMx7d)) that it generated 3 separate loops essentially:

```
myfunction(int):
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, edi
        sub     rsp, 8
        test    edi, edi
        je      .L2
        cmp     edi, 1
        je      .L6
        xor     ebp, ebp
.L4:
        mov     edi, ebx
        xor     edi, ebp
        add     ebp, 1
        call    dosomething3(int)
        cmp     ebp, 1000000
        jne     .L4
.L1:
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
.L2:
        mov     edi, ebx
        add     ebx, 1
        call    dosomething1(int)
        cmp     ebx, 1000000
        jne     .L2
        jmp     .L1
.L6:
        xor     ebx, ebx
.L3:
        mov     edi, ebx
        add     ebx, 1
        xor     edi, 1
        call    dosomething2(int)
        cmp     ebx, 1000000
        jne     .L3
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

But at **-O2** level the checks on `a` are inside the loop:

```
myfunction(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     ebp, edi
        push    rbx
        xor     ebx, ebx
        sub     rsp, 8
        jmp     .L5
.L2:
        mov     edi, ebp
        xor     edi, ebx
        cmp     ebp, 1
        je      .L9
        call    dosomething3(int)
.L3:
        add     ebx, 1
        cmp     ebx, 1000000
        je      .L10
.L5:
        test    ebp, ebp
        jne     .L2
        mov     edi, ebx
        add     ebx, 1
        call    dosomething1(int)
        cmp     ebx, 1000000
        jne     .L5
.L10:
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
.L9:
        call    dosomething2(int)
        jmp     .L3
```

So you'd have to check how your specific compiler handles this.